# https server python based is closing connection after serving the response

Tags: http, https, server, client

I had created simple server in terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, os, socket, ssl
import requests
import string
import time
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
from http.server import HTTPServer,BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from io import BytesIO
import json
import cgi

class ThreadingServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    pass

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        #self.send_header('Content-type', 'Application/json')
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        response = BytesIO()
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        self.wfile.write(b"""{"signingResponse": {"compactidentity": "..SdOwnT70ZZDAjgSmQVP-_0keB_pu4FjkBg5DZDyFf_V5k0EUAY0KCHr2g2a6wOSs-JhsehdYUnrYCfkYItzxLg;info=<http://52.23.250.93:8080/certs/shaken.crt>;alg=ES256;ppt=shaken\n", "TEST": "Nitish","identity": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInBwdCI6InNoYWtlbiIsInR5cCI6InBhc3Nwb3J0IiwieDV1IjoiaHR0cDovLzUyLjIzLjI1MC45Mzo4MDgwL2NlcnRzL3NoYWtlbi5jcnQifQ.eyJhdHRlc3QiOiJBIiwiZGVzdCI6eyJ0biI6WyIxMjM1NTU1MTIxMiJdfSwiaWF0IjoxNDgzMjI4ODAwLCJvcmlnIjp7InRuIjoiMTIzNTU1NTEyMTIifSwib3JpZ2lkIjoiOGE4ZWM2MTgtYzZiOS0zMGFlLWI0MjctYWY0MTA0YjFjMDJjIn0.SdOwnT70ZZDAjgSmQVP-_0keB_pu4FjkBg5DZDyFf_V5k0EUAY0KCHr2g2a6wOSs-JhsehdYUnrYCfkYItzxLg;info=<http://52.23.250.93:8080/certs/shaken.crt>;alg=ES256;ppt=shaken\n", "requestid": "0"}} """)

httpd = ThreadingServer(('192.168.1.2', 8003), RequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, keyfile='/home/nakumar/key.pem', certfile='/home/nakumar/certificate.pem', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Using above code i am trying to simulated the server
now when server receives request from client , it send back the responses and closed the connection , as shown below

Request

```
> POST /stir/v1/signing HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.2:8003
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 331
```

Reponse

```
upload completely sent off: 331 out of 331 bytes
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Server: BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.5.2
< Date: Tue, 09 Oct 2018 12:43:21 GMT
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

So we can see the connection close is coming from server after response is served,

is there way possible ,not to close the connection after response is served .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl Was closing the connection since content length was not present in the response body 
after adding the same it started working

```
> POST /stir/v1/signing HTTP/1.1
Host: [FD00:10:6B50:4510:0:0:0:53]:8101
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 325

* upload completely sent off: 325 out of 325 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: HTTP/1.1 Python/3.5.2
< Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2018 09:13:11 GMT
< Content-type: Application/json
< Content-length: 150
< 
* Connection #1 to host FD00:10:6B50:4510:0:0:0:53 left intact
```